# How to open a local Jupyter Notebook directly on Google Colab without going for the extra step of uploading it on Google Drive?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, repo

I would like to load my jupyter notebook from my local repo directly on Colab, without uploading it first on GDrive. I'm well aware of the possibility to open Github notebooks directly on Colab, but that's not what I'm trying to make, since I would like to directly open notebooks from my local repo and then have the freedom to commit and push whenever I want. Is this possible or do I have to just give up and upload a copy on GDrive and then download the .ipynb everytime I want to save locally?

Answer (score -2):

You can use my library to open Jupyter Notebook and open any local notebook in the same machine instance.

```
!pip install kora -q
from kora import jupyter
jupyter.start()
```

Then click the shown link. It should list local ipynb files. You can then click them to open and edit the files directly.

Comment: But this doesn't really solve my problem. For what I got this just starts a jupyterlab process in the directory I called it from. I already could do that without your library, which I'm sure could be helpful in other ways, but how can I open it in Colab?

Comment: You can use jupyterlab to edit the notebook. If you really want to use Colab, you must mount the drive and copy the notebook to google drive, then open from there using its file ID. `kora.xattr.get_id(filename)`, with URL=colab.to/FILE_ID